# How to open an xpage document from a navigator

Tags: xpages

This is probably a simple answer (I hope it is).  I just haven't figured it out yet.  I have an Accordion Container with Navigators.  In my database I have a normal Notes document being used as a profile document for the user.  I simply would like to open that document from a link on the Navigator in edit mode but I can only get it to open a new doc.  Also, need to check to see if the profile exists and if not, open a new one.  I can open it if in the xPage I set all the fields manually but when it saves, it creates a new document.  Maybe this is the answer, how do I set the data source (document1) when the xpage is opened.  Thank you for your expertise.....

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you have tried, I'll suggest a technique...

In the Data definition for the `<xp:DominoDocument>` set the `ignoreRequestParams="true"` then compute the `<xp.this.documentId>` to be the unid of the Profile document. (This assumes that the "Profile document" is a standard Notes document and not a Notes Profile Document. The latter have many issues and is a bit difficult to acces and manipulate using XPages.)

Comment: I tried this code: var vKey = "MyProfile";
var docProf:NotesDocument = viewProfileLkup.getDocumentByKey(vKey); // Lookup Profile Document for user
return docProf.getUniversalID();  and it returned a 500 error.  viewProfileLkup is defined as the view data source and the document exists in that view.

Comment: The page link node in the navigator simply defines the xpages to open when clicked....

Comment: SOLVED:  I created a sessionScope variable with the UNID in my left navigator (sidebar) that I use for all the xpages in the DB.  Then I used that sessionScope in the Document ID of the data source on the form that I'm trying to open.